# Change string to Pascal case

Tags: c

working on some code. I am a beginner at c so I probably won't understand super complicated syntax. As the question states I have a string read in from the user. "cat dog" and the program changes it to pascal case. "CatDog" As you can see the first letter of each word is capitalized and the spaces are removed. That is where I am having trouble, I cannot figure out how to remove the spaces. I thought of putting in a temp array, but because of scope issues I cannot return the new string array. Thanks in advance. Also I have to stay within the function and cannot create new ones.

```
 #include <stdio.>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

char toUpperCase(char ch){ //changes char to uppercase
return ch - 'a'+ 'A';
}

char toLowerCase(char ch){//changes char to lower case
return ch -'A'+'a';
}


void PascalCase(char* word){//"cat dog" "CatDog"
/*Convert to Pascal case
 It is safe to assume that the string is terminated by '\0'*/
char temp[100];//do not know how to implement
int i;
if (word[0] >= 97 && word[0] <= 122) {
    word[0] = toUpperCase(word[0]);
}
    for (i = 1; i < strlen(word); ++i) {
        if (word[i] >= 65 && word[i] <= 90) {
            word[i] = toLowerCase(word[i]);
        }
        if (word[i] == ' '){
            ++i;
            if (word[i] >= 97 && word[i] <= 122) {
                word[i] = toUpperCase(word[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}



int main(){
 char word[100]; 
 printf("Enter phrase:");
 fgets(word, 100, stdin);

 /*Call PascalCase*/
 PascalCase(word);

 /*Print new word*/
 printf("%s\n", word);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: "because of scope issues I cannot return the new string array". You can if you use dynamic memory allocation. `char *temp = malloc(100);`. But ensure the memory is freed when no longer needed. Another common idiom is for the function to take in a buffer pointer that the caller passes in.

Comment: don't use magic numbers like 65 or 97. `'a'` and `'A'` shows the intent much clearer and works in any charset as long as a to z is contiguous

Answer (score 0):

You can try my code below:

```
  inline char toUpperCase(char c){
    if('a'<=c && c<='z') return c-'a'+'A';
    else return c;
  }
  inline char toLowerCase(char c){
    if('A'<=c && c<='Z') return c-'A'+'a';
    else return c;
  }
  void toPascalCase(char *str){
    int i,j=0; bool first=true;
    for(i=0;str[i];i++){
      if(str[i]==' ') {first=true; continue;}
      if(first) {str[i]=toUpperCase(str[i]); first=false;}
      else str[i]=toLowerCase(str[i]);
      str[j++]=str[i];
    }
    str[j]='\0';
  }
```

Since removing space does not increase the string length, the operation can be done in place. Also, I moved the case check into the `toUpperCase` function so it becomes more convenient to use. Making it inline will enable a faster implementation. I tried different inputs, e.g. "cat dog", or " Cat dog" and the code always gives you "CatDog" (the Pascal case). The boolean variable `first` indicates if the current character is the first one after a space (the beginning of a word that should be capitalized).

Comment: I just added a `toLowerCase` function to ensure that characters that are not first in a word are converted to lower case. Now this code works for inputs like " cAt doG". But in "cat-dog", the 'd' in the "dog" will not be capitalized. You'll get "Cat-dog". I'm not sure if this is OK for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach which makes use of existing functions already available. Not sure what "I have to stay within the function and cannot create new ones" is supposed to mean, hopefully it doesn't invalidate the approach. The chosen string is intended to be tongue-in-cheek.

EDIT: As pointed out by cdlane, `strlwr` is a non-standard function which may not be available. I've added an alternative.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void str2lower(char *input)
{
    int i=0;
    while (input[i])
    {
        input[i] = tolower(input[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}

// returns a new string - caller responsible for freeing the memory
char *pascalCase(char *input)
{
    // create a copy of the string, since strtok modifies its input
    char *tmp = strdup(input);
    // any char in this sring will be used to split the input
    const char *delims = " ";

    // get some memory - same length as original string.
    // **this will be too much** we dont need memory for the sapces
    // that will be removed.
    int len = strlen(input);
    char *result = (char*)calloc(len, 1);

    // return a string that contains chars up to the first
    // char found in the delims string
    char *curWord = strtok(tmp,delims);
    while (curWord != NULL)
    {
        // make the whole word lower-case
        //strlwr(curWord);
        str2lower(curWord);

        // capitalize the first letter
        curWord[0] = toupper(curWord[0]);
        // tack it onto the end of our result
        strcat(result, curWord);
        // get the next word
        curWord = strtok(NULL, delims);
    }
    // dont need this anymore
    free(tmp);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    // http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/realmen.html
    char *result = pascalCase("real programmers don't use pascal");
    printf("%s\n", result);
    free(result);
}
```

Comment: [strlwr( ) function is a non standard function which may not be available in the standard library in C](http://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-strings/c-strlwr-function/)

Answer (score 0):

An attempt to deal with all the specifications and keep it simple:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Convert to Pascal case */
/* It is safe to assume that the string is terminated by '\0' */

void PascalCase(char *string) { // "cat dog" -> "CatDog"

    char *pointer = string;

    while (*pointer != '\0') {
        if (pointer == string) { // first character in string
            *pointer = toupper(*pointer);
        } else {
            *pointer = tolower(*pointer); // character not beginning a word
        }

        while (*pointer == ' ') {
            (void) memmove(pointer, pointer + 1, strlen(pointer)); // remove space from string
            if ((*pointer = toupper(*pointer)) == '\0') { // capitalize if a letter replaces space
                return; // not documented if memmove() leaves original '\0' so CYA
            }
        }

        ++pointer;
    }
}
```

The test for the first character in the string was moved inside the loop so that it would also fall after the `'\0'` test should the function be passed an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use a second buffer but here is another way to do it.
Have two pointers to the buffer and then traverse the string. `isspace` is the standard runtime function to see if a character is space or not.

```
char word[] = "dog cat";

char* q = word;  // set pointer to buffer, use this for moving string forward
char* p = word;  // finding the non space characters

while (*p && *q)
{
  if (isspace(*p))  // skip any spaces
  {
    ++p;
  }
  else // find non-space, make first one capital then move it
  { 
    *p = toupper(*p); 
    while (!isspace(*p) && *p) *q++ = *p++;
  }
}

*q = '\0';

puts(word);
```